# Problema con '\' y la función 'input'

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo un script en el que pido por teclado el directorio, nombre y extensión de un archivo y después lo monto y lo asigno a una variable:

```
import numpy as np

import f06_directories as drc


# Pedimos al usuario que introduzca el directorio en el que se encuentra el
# archivo que contiene los datos.
direct = drc.assembling_direct_arch()
```

Las funciones que uso son las siguientes:

```
def assembling_direct_arch(name=None, extension=None, direct=None):
    """
    Genera una variable en la que se almacena el directorio de un archivo
    con su nombre y extension introducidos por teclado por el usuario.

    Parameters
    ----------
    name: str
        Nombre del archivo.
    extension: str
        Extension del archivo.
    direct: str
        Directorio del archivo.

    Returns
    ----------
    assemble: str
        Directorio con nombre y extension del archivo.
    """
    #
    if name is None:
        name = name_arch()
    if extension is None:
        extension = extension_arch(name)
    if direct is None:
        direct = direct_arch()
    #
    assemble = direct + '\\' + name + extension
    #
    return assemble


def direct_arch():
    """
    Genera una variable en la que se almacena el directorio, introducido
    por teclado por el usuario.
    """
    #
    # Pedimos al usuario que introduzca el directorio.
    direct = input('Introduzca el directorio:\n')
    #
    return direct


def extension_arch(name):
    """
    Genera una variable en la que se almacena la extension de un archivo
    introducido por teclado por el usuario.

    Parameters
    ----------
    name: str
        Nombre del archivo.
    """
    #
    # Pedimos al usuario que introduzca la extension del archivo.
    extension = input('Introduzca la extension del archivo "' + name
                      + '" (incluyendo el punto):\n')
    #
    return extension


def name_arch():
    """
    Genera una variable en la que se almacena el nombre de un archivo
    introducido por teclado por el usuario.
    """
    #
    # Pedimos al usuario que introduzca el nombre del archivo.
    name = input('Introduzca el nombre del archivo:\n')
    #
    return name
```

El problema es que si yo le paso el directorio, el nombre y la extensión siguientes:

> Z:\Trabajos\Python 3\funciones\f00_funciones_generales
>
> a
>
> .cd

La variable direct tiene el valor:

```
Z:\\Trabajos\\Python 3\\funciones\\f00_funciones_generales\\a.cd
```

Es decir, que donde debería haber `'\'`, tenemos `'\\'`.

¿Cómo soluciono este problema?

Comment: Zhisi simplemente se está escapando la barra, esa ruta si la vas a usar en Python es perfectamente válida, `Z:\Trabajos\Python 3\funciones\f00_funciones_generales\a.cd` no lo será.

Comment: Entonces, ¿para trabajar en Python es totalmente funcional? (Si copio esa ruta en el navegador de windows, me da error)

Comment: La cadena debería contener en realidad un solo ``\`` (compruébalo haciendo un `print` de la misma). Lo que contiene dos barras es su versión "representable", la cual además aparecerá entre comillas. Esto es así porque la versión representable debe ser código python válido (tal como lo escribirías en tu código fuente, donde la ``\`` debes meterla dos veces para "escapar" ese carácter especial)

Comment: Tienes razón. La cadena sólo tiene un '\' y haciendo `print` es lo que muestra. Y si en lugar de eso, ejecuto en la consola la variable que almacena la cadena, sale la cadena entre comillas y con '\\'.

Comment: @Zhisi Ya para dejar claro el tema, cuando "ejecutas" una variable en el intérprete interactivo, lo que hace python es `print(repr(variable))`, y eso es lo que te da la versión "representable". Si la `variable` es un objeto, mirará si implementa el método `variable.__repr__()` y lo llamará para obtener la versión "representable", que será la que imprima.

Comment: @Zhisi en conclusión, ¿Que es lo que se debe solucionar? Si saliste de duda puedes eliminar la publicación, saludos!

Comment: @Jorgesys La duda está resuelta, pero considero que puede ser útil para otros ususarios. ¿Por qué habría de borrar la publicación?

Comment: @Zhisi Si consideras que puede ser útil, entonces realiza una respuesta basada en [answer], saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En realidad no hay ningún problema.

Si imprimimos la variable haciendo `print(direct)` obtenemos el valor de la cadena almacenada en `direct` que es exactamente lo que queríamos conseguir:

```
Z:\Trabajos\Python 3\funciones\f00_funciones_generales\a.cd
```

Si por el contrario ejecutamos en la consola directamente la variable `direct` lo que nos devuelve es la versión "representable" de dicha variable, que además aparecerá entre comillas.Esto es así porque la versión representable debe ser código python válido (tal como lo escribirías en tu código fuente, donde la \ debes meterla dos veces para "escapar" ese carácter especial):

```
'Z:\\Trabajos\\Python 3\\funciones\\f00_funciones_generales\\a.cd'.
```

Otra forma de explicarlo es como lo hace @abulafia en los comentarios y que copio parcialmente a continuación:

> Cuando "ejecutas" una variable en el intérprete interactivo, lo que hace python es `print(repr(variable))`, y eso es lo que te da la versión "representable". Si la variable es un objeto, mirará si implementa el método `variable.__repr__()` y lo llamará para obtener la versión "representable", que será la que imprima.